# The ground state of AFM Heisenberg model $H=+J\displaystyle \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} \vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{S}_j$ on the triangular lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-order, spin-models

What is the order -- the ground state of AFM Heisenberg model $H=+J\displaystyle \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{S}_j$ on the triangular lattice, with $J>0$ and nearest neighbor coupling in 2+1d?

It is not RVB? It is a conventional Landau order, or not?

It is gapless with spin-wave?

If it is AFM spin-1 Heisenberg model, do we have gapless spin-1 magnon?

If it is AFM spin-1/2 Heisenberg model, do we have gapless spin-1/2 magnon?

Please correct me if I say something incorrect or imprecise.

---

AFM: for antiferromagnetic, RVB for resonance bond solids.

Comment: AFM: for antiferromagnetic, RVB for resonance bond solids.